# Java Sphinx "Answers Itself"

Tags: java, sphinx4

I'm having a problem with the Sphinx voice recognition library for Java. I am using it to get input and handle it. The first time I get input, it works. The second time, it immediately answers itself before I have a chance to talk. After that, it just continues to answer itself. I tried allocating before every input and deallocating after every input but that doesn't seem to work. What can I do?

---

**Code**:

This is the method that handles getting input:

```
public void getInput() {
        if (using) return;

        using = true;

        if (!allocated) {
            JTalk.speak("Please hold.");

            recognizer.allocate();
            allocated = true;
        }

        JTalk.speak("Speak now.");

        Result result = recognizer.recognize();

        if (result != null) {
            String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();

            JDispatcher.getInstance().matchInput(resultText);
        }

        else {
            JTalk.speak("Try again.");
        }

        using = false;
    }
```

What you need to know:

- This is being called from a `MouseListener` for a `TrayIcon`.
- `speak(String)` runs `say <text>` from the `Runtime`.
- `matchInput(String)` iterates over all registered listeners in an array and tests for matches.

---

**Update 2**:

As per Nikolay Shmyrev's answer, I tried allocating the microphone in the constructor and starting, then stopping, the microphone at the appropriate times in `getInput()`.

Here's the SphinxBridge class:

```
public class SphinxBridge {

    private ConfigurationManager cm;
    private Recognizer recognizer;
    private Microphone microphone;
    private boolean using = false;

    public SphinxBridge() {
        this.cm = new ConfigurationManager(SphinxBridge.class.getResource("input.config.xml"));
        this.recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        this.microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");

        recognizer.allocate();
    }

    public void getInput() {
        if (using) return;

        using = true;

        if (!microphone.startRecording()) {
            JTalk.speak("Cannot start microphone.");
            return;
        }

        JTalk.speak("Speak now.");

        Result result = recognizer.recognize();

        if (result != null) {
            String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();

            JDispatcher.getInstance().matchInput(resultText);
        }

        else {
            JTalk.speak("Try again.");
        }

        microphone.stopRecording();

        using = false;
    }
}
```

However, this still doesn't work. The first, it works fine. However, for all subsequent times, it says `Speak now` and `Try again` at the same time.

---

**Solution:**

From the code above, I simply added

```
    microphone.clear();
```

above the line that starts recording.

Comment: sharing code may help.

Comment: Added. I didn't originally share code because I figured maybe it was a Sphinx bug that was known or someone had a quick solution. I realize now that I should've added it in the first place. Sorry.

Comment: @nrubin29 can you share your project please

Comment: @Abderrahim I don't think I have this code anymore. If you are having a similar issue I could try my best to help you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand how microphone works. It just runs a thread and stores all the audio recorded into the buffer. So when you play a reply it's also stored into a buffer for processing.

You need to call `microphone.stopRecording()` to stop microphone recording while you are playing a TTS reply.

Also you need to call `microphone.clear()` before `startRecording` call to clear the data that was previously recorded. Such data still resides in input buffer.

To get microphone component from Configuration you can use something like:

```
 ConfigurationManager cm;
 ....
 microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
```

Comment: Ok, this is a right direction. You probably also need to call microphone.clear() to clear the data which it recorded. You can do it before microphone.startRecording().

Comment: Thank you so much! Calling `clear()` before I `startRecording()` solved the problem!